# How to index protocol buffer files using apache solr?

Tags: java, apache, indexing, solr, protocol-buffers

I have my data stored in protocol buffer files. I want to index some messages of those protocol buffer files using apache solr. How can I do that?

My protocol buffer file has the following structure:

```
 

    message m1{ //I don't want to index this message
       #### some fields 
    }
    message m2{ //I don't want to index this message
        #### some fields 
    }

    message text{   
       required string content;  // this field I want to index
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to perform the indexation itself, or how to write the schema, or how to extract the data you want to index from your files, or...? Can you be more specific as to your exact problem?

Comment: My question clearly states that "how to index" specific fields of a protocol buffer file.